# Application lenses slow

Tags: 13.04, applications-lens

As I said in title, application lenses are slow. When I click on application lens it takes around 10 seconds for applications to appear. It seems Unity loads application list from hard drive every time I click on application lens. Is there any way to make this faster?

btw every other part of system runs really fast.

Comment: Do you mean all lenses or just the application lens?

Comment: Just application lens, the rest of lenses are pretty fast. When I click on application lens I can see that loading animation, then I wait around 10 seconds and then my apps appear, and I don't have much apps, most of them are preinstalled.